# C++ How to disable plugins in FreeImage?

Tags: c++, plugins, freeimage

I've searched the web on how to do it but I can't find anything about how someone could disable certain plugins in FreeImage. Reading the [Changelog](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/changeslog.html) I see that it's possible but I can't find any documentation. For example I don't need EXR (which needs OpenEXR), JXR (which needs LibJXR) and a few other libraries that could reduce the size on my executable and I also don't need them.

Does anyone know how to disable FreeImage plugins at compile time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you can disable then in the **Plugin.cpp** file, inside **Source/Plugin** directory.

In this file there a function FreeImage_Initialise that initialize the plugins.

You also do not need to compile the libraries, there a low dependency between **PluginTIFF.cpp** and **OpenEXR**, that is the file **half.cpp**.

[image: Plugins initialization list]